# How can I make a function whose execution is not overriden by next function call?

Tags: ios, swift, function, concurrency

Problem:

I have like function to update like in my post.But if a user hits like function fast or continuously .

My UI update of like status is overridden by next function call and causes bug in like counter.

Question:
How can I stop another function call to override the execution of previous function call?

P.s: I guess sample code is not needed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by next function call?

Comment: @Poles: when I press like button once again or continuously the function is called multiple times ?

Comment: Code is nearly *always* helpful. It sounds like your button press initiates some sort of asynchronous network operation. You could possibly use a serial dispatch queue or a Boolean to inhibit operations until the first one has completed.

Comment: you have to show user that something is going on, block UI, show some activity indicator and do when function finish then let user do what he wants

Answer (score 1):

I guess the easiest way is to use a flag variable, and you can set a timer to reset your flag variable later if needed like:

```
var flag = false

func test() {
    if flag == false {
        // your code ...
        print("123")
    }

    flag = true
}

// Set this later
Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 3.0, target: self, selector: #selector("some function"), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
```